# Flaws in guessing game Exceptions and no correct answer

Tags: java, random

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
 public class geussinggame {

  public static void main(String[]args){


System.out.println("max sucks SMorc tryhard");

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean running = true;
boolean geussed = true;
int number = 0;
int input = 0;







while (running) {
    if (geussed) {

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10");
        System.out.println("good luck it's pretty hard ;)");

        number = getRandom(10) ;
        geussed = false;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not in my house ;- Æ)");
    }


     input = sc.nextInt();
    if (input == 0) {
        running= false;








    }
    if (input == 11){
        running= false;

    }
    if (input==30){


        System.out.println("and max thought i didn't know how to program. well geuss what he was wrong ");

        try{
            Thread.sleep(100000);
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

                Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
                System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    else {
        geussed = input == number ;
    }
}

}

public static int getRandom(int max){
    return (int) (Math.random() *max) + 10;
}
```

}

i mean it really doesnt run right and I would like someone to go through it and find what it is because you can never guess a number as it will never guess 1-10 and also I wanna switch the part

```
if (input==30){


    System.out.println("and max thought i didn't know how to program. well 
 geuss what he was wrong ");

    try{
        Thread.sleep(100000);
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

            Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
            System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }

 }
 else {
    geussed = input == number ;
}
}
```

to a string that you input like if you enter "this game sucks" it will shut down but i have tried

```
If (enter.equals("This Game Sucks"))
```

then the code it throws an exception when I thought I already had that covered (of course I had enter initialized in the previous code) but this is the most  recent code as I wanted to try to see if it still worked but it didnt

Updated code

```
  // the ryAN is cool//
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
public class geussinggame {

public static void main(String[]args){


System.out.println("max sucks SMorc tryhard");

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean running = true;
boolean geussed = true;
int number = 0;
int input = 0;
String enter= sc.next();






while (running) {
    if (geussed) {

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10");
        System.out.println("good luck it's pretty hard ;)");

        number = getRandom(10) ;
        geussed = false;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not in my house ;- Æ)");
    }


     input = sc.nextInt();
    if (input == 0) {
        running= false;
    }
    if (input == 11){
        running= false;

    }
    if (enter.equals ("random message"))
{


        System.out.println("and max thought i didn't know how to program. well geuss what he was wrong ");

        try{
            Thread.sleep(100000);
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

                Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
                System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    else {
        geussed = input == number ;
    }
}

}

public static int getRandom(int max){
    return (int) (Math.random() *max) + 10;
}
}
```

if you try to test it (I wouldn't its a shutdown code) it wont run because it throughs an exception

Comment: Debug your application please. That is the simplest way to find out yourself. Also: indent your code correctly, that will make things a lot easiert.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Why have 7, sometimes 8 blank lines in your code? At least you should remove those before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. I removed the check for 30 as it is impossible to enter it. As for closing the program I think this is more than enough.

```
    public class Main {
            static Random rn = new Random();

            public static void main(String args[]) {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String text = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.println("max sucks SMorc tryhard");


                boolean running = true;
                boolean guessed = false;
                int number = 0;
                int input = 0;

                while (running) {
                    if (!guessed) {
                        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10");
                        System.out.println("good luck it's pretty hard ;)");
                        number = getRandom(10);
                        System.out.println(number);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not in my house ;- Æ)");
                    }

                    input = sc.nextInt();

                    if (input <= 0 || input > 11) {
                        running = false;

                        try {
                            System.exit(0);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    } 
                   if (enter.equals ("random message"))                       {
                   System.out.println("and max thought i didn't know how to program. well geuss what he was wrong ");

                   try{
                      Thread.sleep(100000);
                      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

                      Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
                      System.exit(0);
                    }
                  catch (Exception ex){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }


                        if (input == number) {
                            System.out.println("Guessed correctly");
                            guessed = true;
                            running = false;
                        }

                }
            }

            public static int getRandom(int max) {
                return rn.nextInt(max - 1 + 1) + 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If this was what you were looking for please mark it as answered. If not i would be glad to help more

Comment: Not exactly The shutdown code turns off the computer. I want to keep it. the getRandom code works finely though i will aply it to my Geussing game but i want to get my code to run Like my updated version you can check up there ^^^^^^

Comment: Try now, i think it should be fine now